# Filter foreignkey select options on a form based on an object id passed by a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my project I need to filter foreign key select options on a form. I can do that passing a parameter to the `__init__` method of the form like so:

```
class ResultadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
frequencia = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
tolerancia = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
def __init__(self, equipamento_id, *args, **kwargs):
    equipamento_id = kwargs.pop('equipamento_id')
    super (ResultadoForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['teste'].queryset =  Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)

class Meta:
    model = Resultado
    exclude = ['actividade']
```

In the view all I have to do is:

```
form1 = ResultadoForm(equipamento_id)
```

The problem is I am unable to pass the parameter equipamento_id to an inlineformset_factory:

```
form1 = inlineformset_factory(Actividade, Resultado, form=ResultadoForm(equipamento_id), exclude=('actividade',), extra=len(testes_list))
```

This raises an error. How can I pass the parameter equipamento_id to an inlineformset_factory in order to be able to filter the foreignkey options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using django 1.9 you could use `form_kwargs` to pass the data:

```
FormSet1 = inlineformset_factory(Actividade,
                                 Resultado,
                                 form=ResultadoForm,
                                 exclude=('actividade',),
                                 extra=len(testes_list))

formset = FormSet1(form_kwargs={'equipamento_id': equipamento_id})
```

django doc about [`form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms).

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. I also had to remove the first argument, equipamento_id from the __init__ method. Once again, thank you.